# JuMP methods not importing correctly

Tags: julia, julia-jump

I am following the Quickstart guide [here](https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/v0.21.3/quickstart/).  I am just trying to get a very simple JuMP example working.  I copied the following:

```
using JuMP
using GLPK

model = Model(GLPK.Optimizer)
```

Which gives me the error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching Model(::Type{GLPK.Optimizer})
```

All versions of the code above (i.e. using **set_optimizer**) give me similar **undefined** errors.  I am wondering if it is a problem with my version of JuMP or Julia?  pkg st gives me the following output:

```
Status `C:\Users\Owner\.julia\environments\v1.4\Project.toml`
[c52e3926] Atom v0.12.17
[336ed68f] CSV v0.7.4
[a93c6f00] DataFrames v0.21.4
[60bf3e95] GLPK v0.13.0
[2e9cd046] Gurobi v0.8.1
[7073ff75] IJulia v1.21.2
[4076af6c] JuMP v0.21.3
[e5e0dc1b] Juno v0.8.2
[fdba3010] MathProgBase v0.7.8
[2913bbd2] StatsBase v0.33.0
[ddb6d928] YAML v0.4.0
[ade2ca70] Dates 
[37e2e46d] LinearAlgebra
```

I am using Atom to compile my code.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: It's working for me. Could you show us what `versioninfo()` gives you? Just type that in the REPL.

Comment: Where did you run the code, and where did you run `] st`? It might be that Atom is using an older version of JuMP. The code should work with the versions you provide. Note that the forum (https://discourse.julialang.org/c/domain/opt/13) has more people who read than SO who might be able to help.

Comment: If you are experiencing such obscure errors, try to restart the Julia session in Atom.
Also, try not to use the base environment, but create new environment per project so you don't have problems with too many packages which sometimes cause problems.